# How to insert includes in protoc insertion point (Protobuf)?

Tags: c++, dll, protocol-buffers, protoc

I generated from .proto files *.pb.h and *.pb.cc files using `protoc`.
The problem is that i can't export the dll to use it, so I regenrated these files using:
`.\protoc.exe --proto_path=.\Proto\ --cpp_out=dllexport_decl=MY_EXP:.\generated .\ABS.proto`
Thanks to this, I generated the code with **MY_EXP** in all the right places, but I couldn't force the generated .pb.h to #include a header which defines `MY_EXP`.
However, the generated code contains field:`@@protoc_insertion_point(includes)` which means that I probably could add an other includes, but I couldn't understand how I could autogenerate these missing includes in my code.
Thanks.

Comment: I came across this question while struggling with a very similar problem myself. I posted an answer to a similar question here which explains how to create a plugin to leverage the insertion points: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50806894/how-can-i-add-my-own-code-to-java-generated-classes-from-proto-file/58044855#58044855